# Getting location on real device not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm trying to get the user location, running on the simulator, I get the default address, but atleast I know it is working.
I tried to run it on my device but it didn't work.
I try to look for a solution before writing this question but couldn't find something that work for me.
This is my code:

LocationManager:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

static let shared = LocationManager()
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

var callBack:((String)->())?

override init() {
    super.init()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.activityType = .other
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

func checkIfLocationIsEnabled() -> Bool{
    return CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
}

func getUserLocation(){
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, err) in
        if let place = placemarks?.last{
            self.callBack?(place.name!)
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
}
```

This is my getLocation (just calling the getUserLocation and setting the address I get from the callback):

```
    func getLocation(_ label: UILabel) -> String{
    guard let comment = self.mView.addCommentTextField.text else { return ""}
    LocationManager.shared.getUserLocation()
    var addressString = ""
    LocationManager.shared.callBack = { address in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            label.text = "\(address), \(comment)"
            addressString = address
        }
    }
    return addressString
}
```

This is how I call getLocation:

```
 self.mView.inLabel.isHidden = false
        self.getLocation(self.mView.inLabel)
```

Comment: did you ask for required permissions (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager)?

Comment: @KirilS. Yes, it does work on the simulator but not on the real device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking closer at your code, I see that you are asking permissions like this:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

But `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` is asynchronous call, you need to wait for user response before you can use any location services:

> When the current authorization status is `CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined`, this method runs **asynchronously** and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location services.
>   ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization))

Also notice that it will only work if status is `notDetermined`. Any other status would not trigger it. So firstly:

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
    // already authorized, can use location services right away
}
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    // wait, don't call any location-related functions until you get a response
}
```

If location permissions are set to anything else, no point to ask for them. 
And then your class is already `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, so:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // do something with new status, e.g.
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        // good, now you can start accessing location data
    }
    // otherwise, you can't
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I still have the same problem. I tried to debug and I do see that the status is AuthorizeWhenInUse, I don't get any error but it just won't get the location.